# how to use datediff to group Monday to Sunday when first date equals Sunday

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, group

Recognizing this is a common question, answered many times, I've not yet found a solution for my query.

My SQLServer @@DateFirst = 7 (Sunday) and I'm trying to Group a period of Invoice [Date]s by Week Starting Monday to Sunday.

The Query works fine but Sunday Dates are being grouped into the following Mondays Group. I understand why this is, but can't find a solution. I can't create Functions, so these methods don't help either.

```
SELECT

      DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0, [DATE]), 0) AS 'DATE GROUP'
      ,[BRANCH]
      ,[SUNDTYPE]
      ,COUNT([INV_NUM]) AS 'Number of Sundrys'
          ,SUM([COST]) AS 'Sundry Rev'

  FROM Invoice_Table
  WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN '2022-03-07 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-03-13 00:00:00.000'
  
  GROUP BY DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0, [DATE]), 0), SUNDTYPE, BRANCH
```

SQL Server is 2012

DATEADD and DATEDIFF to group all dates to the Monday of every week, Expecting Monday to Sunday Dates to all be Grouped together

Comment: I don't know about your db, but it seems that there are common results for the generic group: dateadd, sundtype, branch. Try to change query with one less and see if sun+mon are still grouped together. If not - the one you omit has common values for both dates. That's may be a clue to what is wrong. So write another query with where clause (not group) and find out the records cause the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fake it out by shifting the date in question BACK 1 day.  This way, what you are LOOKING FOR is

```
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
```

But the WEEK functionality is based on

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
```

So if your data based on this week for example is

```
Date IS    What you ARE getting   What you want
Fri Apr 1    Week X               Week X
Sat Apr 2    Week X               Week X
Sun Apr 3    Week Y               Week X 
Mon Apr 4    Week Y               Week Y
Tue Apr 5    Week Y               Week Y
```

Just subtract 1 day from the date in question that is being checked against the week function(), thus rolling all days back 1 makes Monday look like Sunday which is your correct break point, and Sunday rolls back to the previous week's Saturday.

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0, dateadd( day, -1, [Date])), 0) AS 'DATE GROUP'
```

Then you can just re-add the date back 1 day to re-calibrate to Monday for display purposes.

Comment: Nice! So simple :)